# Integral of the product of two functions equals zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $\alpha:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that 
$$ \int_{a}^{b}\alpha(x)h(x) \; dx=0$$ for any continuous function $h:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(a)=h(b)=0$. How can I prove that $\alpha(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: Suppose $\alpha(x_0)\ne 0$, and so $\alpha$ is nonzero (say positive) on some interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$. Can you make up an appropriate function $h$ that will give you a nonzero integral?

Comment: I was thiking in that option but I can not find a continuous funcion $h$. The big trouble is that I can not find a function such that $h(a)=h(b)=0$

Comment: Try taking any function you like and multiplying it by $(x-a)(x-b)$. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(x)=\alpha (x)$ for $a+\epsilon <x <b-\epsilon$, $h(a)=h(b)=0$ and let $h$ have straight line graphs in $[a,a+\epsilon]$ as well as $[b-\epsilon,b]$. Write down the given equation and let $\epsilon \to 0$. You will get $\int (\alpha (x))^{2})\, dx=0$ so $\alpha =0$. [ Note that $h$ is bounded by $\sup \{|\alpha (x)|: a\leq x \leq b\}=M$ say. Hence $\int _a ^{a+\epsilon} |\alpha (x) h(x)| \, dx\leq M^{2} \epsilon \to 0$. Similar argument for integral over $[b-\epsilon,b]$].